Grid in the picture from leaflet-simple-map-screenshoter
I use to leaflet-simple-map-screenshoter to take screenshots in a leaflet. I use to the default plugin. Why do I see a grid in the pictures?
let pluginOptions = {
   cropImageByInnerWH: true, // crop blank opacity from image borders
   hidden: false, // hide screen icon
   preventDownload: false, // prevent download on button click
   domtoimageOptions: {}, // see options for dom-to-image
   position: 'topleft', // position of take screen icon
   screenName: 'screen', // string or function
   iconUrl: ICON_SVG_BASE64, // screen btn icon base64 or url
   hideElementsWithSelectors: ['.leaflet-control-container'], // by default hide map controls All els must be child of _map._container
   mimeType: 'image/png', // used if format == image,
   caption: null, // string or function, added caption to bottom of screen
   captionFontSize: 15,
   captionFont: 'Arial',
   captionColor: 'black',
   captionBgColor: 'white',
   captionOffset: 5,
   // callback for manually edit map if have warn: "May be map size very big on that zoom level, we have error"
   // and screenshot not created
   onPixelDataFail: async function({ node, plugin, error, mapPane, domtoimageOptions }) {
       // Solutions:
       // decrease size of map
       // or decrease zoom level
       // or remove elements with big distanses
       // and after that return image in Promise - plugin._getPixelDataOfNormalMap
       return plugin._getPixelDataOfNormalMap(domtoimageOptions)
   }
}

When i take screenshot from examples I don't see these gaps.


#mapPassport *,
#mapPassport *::before,
#mapPassport *::after {
    border-width: initial !important;
    border-style: initial !important;
    border-color: initial !important;
}


Please add an explanation to why this solves the issue. This will greatly benefit OP and any others with the same issue.
